# Can I use C++ header files in kernel part of a CUDA code?

Tags: c++, c, cuda

I want to compare two strings in a kernel function. Can I use strcomp in  file?
Generally, can I use C++ libraries in my CUDA code?

Comment: No - you're doing something very wrong if you feel that you need to do this - what exactly are you trying to achieve with your CUDA kernel ?

Comment: Using lots of thread for searching in a graph of words. Each one of them decides its next step based one comparing the destination word and the word of current node. So, I think each one of them needs to compare these two string in each step.

Comment: The problem with this type of application is that your warps are going to be highly divergent, since each thread will be following a non-deterministic path through a bunch of branches. I can't see this being very efficient. Are you sure it's worth doing this on a GPU ?

Comment: What if I use texture memory. I read somewhere that it is better for non-coalesced memory readings.

Answer (score 1):

It would surprising if the CUDA libraries include a kernel-side version of the C++ standard library, which you would need in order for this to work, since (as Paul R noted in a comment), this and many other standard functions are not particularly appropriate for GPU acceleration.

According to the CUDA language rules, only `__device__` functions are callable from the Device.  Functions such as `strcmp` are not declared as `__device__` in the C++ standard library, so if the CUDA language does not include them as extensions -- and it does not, since the CUDA Programming Guide does not include any documentation of them -- then they cannot be used in kernels.

What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I am gathering information right now. I am writing the code in C++ and want to change it to CUDA after that.